# Can I draw a triangle with only two measures given?

Tags: triangles

I want to know whether I can draw a triangle with only two measures given. The base length should be 6 and an angle from the base should be 45°. Is it possible?  Help me out ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try drawing a picture to convince yourself that this data does not determine the triangle uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an infinity of triangles with base length $6$ and base angle $45$ degrees.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example where we have infinity many solutions .

Since the angle sum of a triangle is $180 $ degrees and you are given one angle of $45$ you may choose a second angle between $0$ and $135 $ and construct a triangle.

Thus the answer is not unique.